# In C++, why does <cctype> define both std::isspace and ::isspace?

Tags: c++

And why are most C++ compilers able to deduce the type of `::isspace` and implicitly convert it to `std::function`, but they are not able to do so for `std::isspace`?

Please see [the following](https://godbolt.org/g/WmPKCJ]) which does not compile:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>

template <typename Functish>
bool bar1(Functish f) { return f('a'); }

inline bool bar2(std::function<bool(char)> f) { return f('a'); }

#if 1
#define ff &std::isspace
#else
#define ff &::isspace
#endif

#if 0
bool foo()
{
    return bar1(ff);
}
#else
bool foo()
{
    return bar2(ff);
}
#endif
```

Of the compilers supported by Compiler Explorer, ELLCC seems to be the only one where `std::isspace` has the deducibility/convertibility that I would expect.

Comment: That's why its better to use the plain old `.h` headers, because they are predictable

Comment: I think it has to do with `using`

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple overloads of `std::isspace`, but only one `::isspace`.

The header <cctype> declares a function `int std::isspace(int)`, and it also maybe declares the same function in the global namespace (it doesn't have to though).

The header <locale> defines a function template `template <class CharT> bool std::isspace(CharT, const std::locale&)`.

The header <ctype.h> declares a function `int isspace(int)`, and it may also declare the same function in the namespace `std` (it doesn't have to though).

It seems likely that on compilers besides ELLCC, <cctype> includes <locale> (or both `std::isspace` overloads are declared somewhere else and included into both headers).  The standard only specifies what symbols the standard headers must declare; it doesn't prohibit them from declaring other symbols that aren't required.

Since `std::isspace` is overloaded, you'll have to cast it to `int(*)(int)` so that the compiler knows which overload to select.

Comment: Godbolt's ellcc appears to use libc++, whereas others use libstdc++. In the latter case, the header that pulls in `<locale>`'s `std::isspace` is actually `<functional>`.